# Regex to seperate multiple items on a single line

Tags: regex

I have a set of results that I would like to parse out using Regex and I can't seem to find an expression that works. On each line in a txt file, there are 2 entries each containing a quantity up to 100 followed by an item name of varying lengths and spaces.

Example:

```
7 BALLS OF STRING 13 CARDBOARD BOXES
14 ROCKS 12 PENCILS
```

I would like to match the 1st entry with the quantity in group 1, and the 2nd entry with it's quantity in group 2.

Comment: What language or tool are you using? How did you attempt to solve this?

Comment: Please add some example attempts that you have tried. The community is far more likely to be able to help you out once you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression pattern and use it while reading the file, line per line:

```
^(\d*\s[A-Z\s]*)\s(\d*\s[A-Z\s]*)$
```

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/18dege/1

Here a few details:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string, `$` the end of it
- `\d*` matches any number (0 or more) of numeric characters greedy (equal to `[0-9]*`)
- `\s` matches a white space character (e.g. tab, space, etc.)
- `[A-Z\s]*` matches any number (0 or more) of uppercase characters and whitespace greedy
- `()` creates a matching group (to extract some parts of the string)

---

According to the comment below, uppercase letters can be followed by lowercase letters, which should not be matched. An example for this would be:

```
7 BALLS OF STRING 13 CARDBOARD BOXES
14 ROCKS 12 PENCILS
18 TABLES 3 BLANKETS sewn with patches
```

To match this pattern, you can use the following regular expression:

```
^(\d*\s[A-Z\s]*?)[a-z\s]*\s(\d*\s[A-Z\s]*?)[a-z\s]*$
```

As an update to the above pattern, I've added the following:

- `[a-z\s]*` between the statements (not in the group) and after the second statement, to match a lowercase string
- `(\d*\s[A-Z\s]*?)` I've added a question mark `?`, to make the matching non-greedy. This prevents adding the white space between the uppercase and the lowercase part to the matching group. It is now required to have an end of string character `$` at the end of the pattern, otherwise, the second group would not match enough characters.

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/18dege/2

Comment: Amazing.  This worked.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey,

They above worked great, however I found some additional exception cases in this data set that I was hoping I could get some help on.

In addition to the above, I also have entries with single entries on a line as well as entries with notes.  All of the data I want is in all Caps, the notes I don't need.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.



7 BALLS OF STRING 13 CARDBOARD BOXES
14 ROCKS 12 PENCILS
18 TABLES
3 BLANKETS sewn with patches

Comment: So, the lowercase letters are always after the uppercase letters and should not be matched?

Comment: @ryang I've edited the answer and added another pattern to also match strings with lowercase characters after the uppercase characters.